# Is there any other way I can configure JDK

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run an app in Visual Studio Code, but I keep on getting this error:

> Your environment is not configured properly and you will not be able
> to execute local builds. Verify that your environment is configured
> according to the system requirements described at
> https://docs.nativescript.org/environment-setup.html#windows-android.

I have installed JDK, but the error keeps on showing. Is there anything I am doing wrong? Please help.

I am also getting these two warnings:

1. > Error executing command 'javac'. Make sure you have installed The Java Development Kit (JDK) and set JAVA_HOME environment variable
2. > WARNING: The Java Development Kit (JDK) is not installed or is not configured properly

Comment: Do you have an environment variable JAVA_HOME that points to the /bin directory where you installed the JDK?  Are you sure you have a JDK and not the JRE? 
 https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial

Comment: @duffymo JAVA_HOME should point to directory containing the `bin`, not the `bin` directory.

Comment: Fair enough.  I knew I'd remember it the wrong way.  It'd be better to not require an environment variable.  I don't have JAVA_HOME set on any machine I work on.  It's better that way.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the "Start" icon and go to "System"

[image: System]

2. On the page appeared, on the right side, click on "Advanced system settings"

[image: AdvancedSettings]

3. On the dialog that appears, click on "Environment variables"

[image: EnvironmentVariablesButton]

4. On the new dialog, in the "System" section click on "New" button

[image: NewButtonToClick]

5. In the appeared dialog add `JAVA_HOME` variable, and specify the folder, where you have JDK installed, for example: `C:\Program Files\java1.8.0\`
   Note, that this value should not point to the `bin` folder.
6. Accept this dialog.
7. In the list of system environment variables find and open "PATH" environment variable dialog and add this value to the PATH values list: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

[image: PathVariableElement]

[image: listOfPathValues]

8. Restart Visual Studio for Code.

That's it.